# Email Sends in Sales Cloud is not populating

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have a data extension stored in Salesforce Data Extension folder with subscriber key as 18 digit contact ID. We are doing sends using send flow(manual send) using this Data Extension. But somehow email sends related list in sales cloud is not populating. Can someone help me to understand if i have missed something?

Though IERs are populating in sales cloud.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you need to use the Salesforce Send activity to have the email sends list in sales cloud populated.

Comment: This is not correct. If the data extension is within the Salesforce Data Extensions folder structure it doesn't matter if you do a manual send or use an activity for automation. Both will populate tracking results in Salesforce CRM if the connector is setup correctly and the checkbox "Send tracking results to Salesforce" is activated (default setting for connected accounts) in the email send configuration.

Comment: I'm afraid that your comment is not completely accurate. The "Send Tracking Results to Sales Cloud" is present in the email activity in Journey Builder, and is not present in a classic User Initiated Send.

Comment: For automation purposes you of course have to use the "Salesforce Email Send" activity instead of a "User initiated Send". In this regard my comment was indeed not 100% detailed.

Answer (score 0):

The Marketing Cloud uses the custom object "Individual Email Results" to store subscriber specific tracking data. It is part of the Marketing Cloud connect package.

**When you see data coming in on the IER related list the connection is working as expected.**

The Email Sends related list on a contact shows emails that are sent using the native CRM email functionality.

This can be a bit confusing as Marketing Cloud Connect also creates an email sends tab in the configuration that refers to Marketing Cloud sends.